# Laravel Eloquent multi relationship

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I am fairly new to Laravel and I can't seem to get my head around the documentation in terms of the data I'm looking to fetch.

Essentially, I have a bunch of brands which are linked to a site (a site being a website). A site can have one or more brands, and a brand can have one or more categories. Likewise, a site can have one or more categories, and I only want to categories for a brand which are also linked to the site's categories.

My database schema (simplified) is as follows:

```
Brand
-----------------
id (int)
name (varchar)
```

```
Category
-----------------
id (int)
name (varchar)
```

```
Site
-----------------
id (int)
name (varchar)
```

```
Brand_Category
-----------------
brand_id (int)
category_id (int)
```

```
Brand_Site
-----------------
brand_id (int)
site_id (int)
```

```
Category_Site
-----------------
category_id (int)
site_id (int)
slug (varchar)
```

What I'm looking to do is get the following:

GIVEN I have a site_id
WHEN I query for an array of brands linked to a site
THEN return an array of brands containing an array of categories where the categories must also have a relationship with sites

Whilst all of the above works, I can't seem to also fetch the `slug` value for the category when it is shown on the brand.

I've tried the varying combinations of relationship types and think this is how Laravel's models should be configured:

**Site**: belongsToMany Brand_Site

**Site**: belongsToMany Site_Category

**Brand**: belongsToMany Brand_Category

**Brand**: belongsToMany Brand_Site

**Category**: belongsToMany Category_Site

**Category**: belongsToMany Brand_Category

**Brand_Site**: hasMany Brand

**Brand_Site** hasMany Site

**Brand_Category**: hasMany Brand

**Brand_Category**: hasMany Category

**Site_Category**: hasMany Site

**Site_Category**: hasMany Category

A query for brands having sites does seem to work fine:

```
$brands = BrandSiteMap::where('site_id', $site_id)
    ->where('status', BrandSiteMap::STATUS_ACTIVE)
    ->whereHas('site', function ($query){
        $query->where('status', Brand::STATUS_ACTIVE);
    });
```

Here is the relationship for `brandCategory` below:

```
public function brandCategory()
{
    return $this->hasMany(BrandCategoryMap::class, 'brand_id', 'brand_id');
}
```

And in my collection it works to fetch categories:

```
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        $categories = [];
        foreach ($this->brandCategory as $bc) {
            $categories[] = [
                'id' => $bc->category->id,
                'name' => $bc->category->name,
                'slug' => $bc->slug
            ];
        }

        return [
            'id' => $this->brand->id,
            'name' => $this->brand->name,
            'categories' => $categories
        ];
    }
```

Which outputs:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Test brand name",
    "categories": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Test Category",
        "slug": null,
    }]
}]
```

The `slug` above is `null` and I can't seem to figure out how/where to fetch that data.

**EDIT**:

I may have figured this myself after 48 hours of trying and 15 mins after posting this! I have added the following to BrandSiteMap:

```
public function categorySite()
{
    return $this->hasOne(CategorySiteMap::class, 'category_id', 'category_id');
}
```

And then I can reference the slug using:

```
'slug' => $bc->categorySite->slug
```

Which gives me the value, however, I'm concerned it will only fetch the first one (given the hasOne) and not the correct one (linked by site_id).

Comment: `Brand` should `belongToMany` `Category` not `Brand_Category` (the same for `Site` and `SiteCategory`).

Comment: I see, so `Brand` has a method of `belongsToMany` `Category` (same with `Site`), but the intermediate table `BrandCategory` has `hasOne` for both?

Comment: You could do the `hasOne` on the pivot model but you shouldn't need to.

Comment: Why are you writing a custom to array function? If you load the relationship it will be transformed correctly, if you need more functionality use Fractal or Eloquent Resources

Comment: Martin, it is an Eloquent Resource. It has a toArray method which spits out the way I want which is then returned as a JsonResource.